# Bootstrap-select search does not appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-select

So I'm having some trouble with integrating the select with search box using bootstrap-select (v1.14.0-beta3) and bootstrap v5.3.1 in react. I looked into a lot of similar questions with the same problem here but none seems to work.

**Component.js:**

```
const SecondContactForm = () => {
  return (
    <select id='sall' className='selectpicker' data-live-search='true'>
      <option data-tokens='ketchup mustard'>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
      <option data-tokens='mustard'>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
      <option data-tokens='frosting'>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    </select>
  );
};

export default SecondContactForm;
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <!--  google font roboto + Poppins:  -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- end google fonts -->

    <!-- bootstrap-select: -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"
    />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/i18n/defaults-en_US.min.js"></script>

    <!-- end  bootstrap-select    -->

    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body
    data-bs-spy="scroll"
    data-bs-target="#navbar-menu"
    data-bs-smooth-scroll="true"
    tabindex="0"
    data-bs-threshold="[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 1]"
  >

   
    <div id="root"></div>

   
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.BootstrapVersion = '5.3.1';
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ liveSearch: true });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Also, the last script does not make any difference, is just a solution I found somewhere that didn't work for me

PS: I did not include `app.js` or `index.js` because they are just returning the component

**EDIT:**
Also, at first, the select was not showing at all, because bootstrap-select.min.js had that `display:hidden` property so I had to include a css like `display: block!important` for the select component